# The method execute() is undefined for the type Mirror.Accounts.Insert

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am creating a server side Dynamic Web Project using Java and Eclipse IDE for Google Glass Mirror API. In my web project I have a `lib` folder under WEB-INF

In  the lib folder i have added the following .jar files

- google-api-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
- google-api-services-mirror-v1-rev66-1.19.0.jar
- google-collections-1.0-rc2.jar
- google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
- google-http-client-jackson-1.19.0.jar

My server side code is

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GlassAuthenticateUser extends HttpServlet{

public static Mirror getMirrorService() throws GeneralSecurityException,
IOException, URISyntaxException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(MIRROR_ACCOUNT_SCOPES)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
            new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();
    Mirror service = new Mirror.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
    return service;
}

public static void createAccount(Mirror mirror, String userToken, String accountName,
        String authTokenType, String authToken) {
    try {
        Account account = new Account();
        List<AuthToken> authTokens = Lists.newArrayList(
                new AuthToken().setType(authTokenType).setAuthToken(authToken));
        account.setAuthTokens(authTokens);
        mirror.accounts().insert(
                userToken, ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountName, account).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{

     //TO DO             
     }
}
```

}

I am getting the following error

> The method execute() is undefined for the type Mirror.Accounts.Insert

Why is that so? I have download the latest Google API java client and used them in my project. However, it is unable to also resolve the `GoogleCredential` class

Can anyone suggest which .jar files should I be adding to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure why you have the google-api-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar. Have you tried the library at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2?

Comment: yes @PabloC I downloaded the latest version from that link..version  1.18.0 is the latest one

Comment: @PabloC: Am I doing anything wrong? although its Java can u suggest how to go about writing the code

Comment: I've downloaded that libarary and it does *not* contain google-api-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar. I think you'll need to make sure you're using google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar

Comment: @PabloC: Yes you are right too...how did u generate the authToken?

Comment: The authToken is generated by you. It's a string that allows the glassware to access the resources it needs. Assuming those are your resources, you need to decide how to secure them. That is beyond the scope of this question, but I suggest you do research into OAuth. Maybe start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the source jar for `google-api-client-1.18.0-rc`, when you need the class jar. You should be able to download the latest bundle from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2 and then extracting `google-api-java-client/libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar` from the downloaded zip file.

Comment: That's what I said in the comment above.

Comment: Hey i added the jar files as u mentioned and the errors were resolved. However, there is one error setServiceAccountScopes(MIRROR_ACCOUNT_SCOPES) takes a Collection<String> as argument. so then do I need to create a List of strings and add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth to that list

Comment: That sounds different than the compilation problems you've been seeing, so it is best asked as a separate question on SO.

Comment: @PabloC - Sorry, I didn't see your comments when I replied. If you post yours as an answer, I'm happy to delete my answer for you to get it accepted.